# method for implementing regression tree on raster data - python

Tags: python, regression, weka, raster, landsat

I'm trying to build and implement a regression tree algorithm on some raster data in python, and can't seem to find the best way to do so. I will attempt to explain what I'm trying to do:

My desired output is a raster image, whose values represent lake depth, call it depth.tif. I have a series of raster images, each representing the reflectance values in different Landsat bands, say [B1.tif, B2.tif, ..., B7.tif] that I want to use as my independent variables to predict lake depth.

For my training data, I have a shapefile of ~6000 points of known lake depth. To create a tree, I extracted the corresponding reflectance values for each of those points, then exported that to a table. I then used that table in weka, a machine-learning software, to create a 600-branch regression tree that would predict depth values based on the set of reflectance values. But because the tree is so large, I can't write it in python manually. I ran into the python-weka-wrapper module so I can use weka in python, but have gotten stuck with the whole raster part. Since my data has an extra dimension (if converted to array, each independent variable is actually a set of ncolumns x nrows values instead of just a row of values, like in all of the examples), I don't know if it can do what I want. In all the examples for the weka-python-wrapper, I can't find one that deals with spatial data, and I think this is what's throwing me off.

To clarify, I want to use the training data (which is a point shapefile/table right now but can- if necessary- be converted into a raster of the same size as the reflectance rasters, with no data in all cells except for the few points I have known depth data at), to build a regression tree that will use the reflectance rasters to predict depth. Then I want to apply that tree to the same set of reflectance rasters, in order to obtain a raster of predicted depth values *everywhere*.

I realize this is confusing and I may not be doing the best job at explaining. I am open to other options besides just trying to implement weka in python, such as sklearn, as long as they are open source. My question is, can what I described be done? I'm pretty sure it can, as it's very similar to image classification, with the exception that the target values (depth) are continuous and not discrete classes but so far I have failed. If so, what is the best/most straight-forward method and/or are there any examples that might help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have had some experience using LandSat Data for the prediction of environmental properties of soil, which seems to be somewhat related to the problem that you have described above.  Although I developed my own models at the time, I could describe the general process that I went through in order to map the predicted data.

For the training data, I was able to extract the LandSat values (in addition to other properties) for the spatial points where known soil samples were taken.  This way, I could use the LandSat data as inputs for predicting the environmental data.  A part of this data would also be reserved for testing to confirm that the trained models were not overfitting to training data and that it predicted the outputs well.

Once this process was completed, it would be possible to map the desired area by getting the spatial information at each point of the desired area (matching the resolution of the desired image).  From there, you should be able to input these LandSat factors into the model for prediction and the output used to map the predicted depth.  You could likely just use Weka in this case to predict all of the cases, then use another tool to build the map from your estimates.

I believe I whipped up some code long ago to extract each of my required factors in ArcGIS, but it's been a while since I did this.  There should be some good tutorials out there that could help you in that direction.

I hope this helps in your particular situation.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are not using any spatial information to build your tree
(such as information on neighboring pixels), just reflectance.  So, you can
apply your decision tree to the pixels as if the pixels were all in a
one-dimensional list or array.

A 600-branch tree for a 6000 point training data file seems like it may be
overfit.  Consider putting in an option that requires the tree to stop splitting
when there are fewer than N points at a node or something similar.  There may
be a pruning factor that can be set as well.  You can test different settings
till you find the one that gives you the best statistics from cross-validation or
a held-out test set.